# Is there a way to activate the Nitro engine for UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a paid-for page-flip webpage on my web server. If I visit this page using mobile Safari, the page functions fine.

But when I visit the webpage through my app which uses UIWebView, the page does not function properly. I am assuming this problem is JS-related.

Through some research I discovered that the mobile Safari has a new JS engine called Nitro which has enabled a lot of the functionalities and performance boosts that don't seem to be available to UIWebView.

Is there a way for me to make UIWebView behave as if it's the mobile Safari viewer? Or if you have any ideas about a possible workaround, I'd appreciate that as well.

Comment: Please stop writing tags in titles.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no.

The Nitro engine is built into the OS and is not made available to standard UIWebViews. It would require jailbreak type access to make this work if it is even possible. If you hope to release to the App Store, you will need to find a different workaround.

Comment: @Gibson The short answer is: investigate what the issue is and fix it. You're asking for a workaround to a problem that is ill-defined. No one on Stack Overflow can do that.

Comment: Your question isn't formatted to get an answer how to improve the efficiency of your code. You will either need to edit your question, or call this one answered and ask a new, more specific question.